# Why does Chrome DevTools sometimes save source files very slowly?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes when I'm editing JavaScript or HTML code in Chrome DevTools' Sources editor, when I press CTRL-S to save the file, the file does not actually save to disk until after several minutes have passed.  Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

Other details of what is happening are as follows:

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10, using Chrome 40.0.2214.95 (update: the problem continues on Ubuntu 15.04 and Chrome 42.0.2311.135).  After I hit CTRL-S to save, the hard drive i/o light is on constantly, and the output of

```
$ sudo iotop
```

contains a line like this:

```
IO>     | COMMAND
97.29 % | chrome [BrowserBlocking]
```

This state continues for more than a minute.  I haven't measured how long it takes, but it may have continued for 10 minutes this time.  It appears that restarting Chrome can fix the problem, but I'd like a better fix than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was caused by the fact I had Chrome Devtools' Workspaces configured to index the files in two node_modules directories which contain a total of 77,000 files.  Now that I set it to ignore those directories, the problem appears to have gone away.

What gave me the idea that this might be the problem, besides the reasonable assumption that the node_modules directories contained a lot of files, was that `iotop` reported Chrome was doing a great deal of *reading* from, but not *writing* to, the drive.